# Index/Match Visible Cells Only

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets. The first holds a list of projects as follows:

```
Project ID    Project Name
1             Project 1
2             Project 2
3             Project 3
```

The second holds comments related to the projects:

```
Project ID    Comment
1             First Comment
1             Second Comment
2             Third Comment
3             Fourth Comment
3             Five Comment
```

My goal is to filter the comments list to only show the comments related to projects that are displayed, so if I filter out Projects 2 and 3, the comments list only shows as follows:

```
Project ID    Comment
1             First Comment
1             Second Comment
```

I am able to filter comments currently by determining if their ID matches an ID in the field, and if so, I have a column filter applied to only show matches. This is done in case someone deleted a project but did not delete the comments related to a project.

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH([@[Project ID]],ProjectWorksheet[Project ID], 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

The problem I have is that if I filter out projects, it shows all comments because Excel is matching against all projects even if they are hidden by the filter instead of only showing comments that match "displayed" projects.

I only want comments shown by the displayed projects.

I have a macro in another workbook that Joins fields based on if the row of data is hidden or not, but is this methodology something I can use so that I can only see comments of projects that are displayed (visible). Here is the macro:

```
Function JoinAll(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
Application.Volatile
For Each a In rng
If a = BaseValue And a.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
JoinAll = JoinAll & IIf(JoinAll = "", "", delim) & a(1, 7)
End If
Next a
End Function
```

If possible, I would love to use a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit:* After re-reading your original question, I believe what you really require is a list of *Project IDs* from the Comments table that are not hidden in the *Projects* table. If that can be drawn out, the associated comments can be easily retrieved.

I thought I'd offer a solution using an array formula with `SUBTOTAL` to determine whether a project ID had been *hidden*. I opted for a more general worksheet cell reference style rather than your tabled layout but it shouldn't be hard to transcribe. This is my sample data layout.

[image]

The array formula in D8 is:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$8:$A$99,SMALL(IFERROR(INDEX(ROW($1:$92)+NOT(SUBTOTAL(102,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($A$8:$A$99,$A$1:$A$6,0))))*1E+99,,),1E+99),ROW(1:1))),"")`
This requires *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* rather than simply *Enter*. Once entered correctly, it can be filled down as necessary.

The standard formula in E8 is:
`=IF(LEN($D8),IFERROR(INDEX($B$8:$B$99,SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$92)+(($A$8:$A$99<>$D8)*1E+99),,),COUNTIF($D$8:$D8,$D8))),""),"")`
Fill down as necessary.

With *Project 2* hidden, these are the results.

[image]

I suspect that your own project is a bit more complicated than the sample data you provided but perhaps this can help. When transcribing for your own purposes, remember that `ROW(1:92)` is the *position within* `B8:B99`, not the actual row on the worksheet.

The array processing is heavily dependent upon the number of rows being examined. In addition, the `INDIRECT` function is considered volatile and will recalculate whenever anything in the workbook changes so expect some calculation lag for large blocks of data.

I've made that sample mockup workbook available on my OneDrive [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=161352CE07628E22!3416&authkey=!AEHfCIZGOCF6xWY&ithint=file%2cxlsx) for you to reference and download. Post back in comments if you run into problems.

[Remove_Comments_from_Hidden_Projects.xlsx](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=161352CE07628E22!3416&authkey=!AEHfCIZGOCF6xWY&ithint=file%2cxlsx)

Comment: Based on the Project ID, shouldn't "Third Comment" be displayed?

Comment: @Kode - I didn't completely catch the OP's question the first time around and got the idea of retrieving the comments backwards. I've rewritten the proposed solution with an array formula that more closely attacks the true issue.

Comment: We may be getting closer. I only have two sheets, one for projects and another for comments. I only the comments sheet to be filtered by visible projects in the projects sheet. I believe your example has three "sheets". Appreciate all the help this far!

Comment: UPDATE: I am able to set a field value as "visible" with a number 1 using the following: =(AGGREGATE(3,5,[@[Project ID]])>0)+0  I then pull this into my second sheet of "Comments" via an index match as follows: =IFERROR(INDEX(Projects[Visible],MATCH([@[Project ID]],Projects[Project ID],0)),"")  From this point I can apply a filter in the "Comments" sheet to only show the "visible" cells (the ones that have a 1). The only problem is that when I filter the values in the "Projects Sheet", it doesn't automatically reapply the filter in my "Comments" sheet. It has to be done manually.

Comment: I was able to create a simple macro in the comments sheet that applied the filter when the sheet is "activated". Problems solved! Given the effort of jeeped, I am still giving the bounty as it helped solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you have Excel 2007 or later, and both lists have a filter (AutoFilter) applied, there's a cool way to do it using AutoFilter:

```
Sub FilterChildFromParent(ByRef wksParent As Worksheet, _
    ByRef wksChild As Worksheet)

    Dim i As Integer                ' Loop counter
    Dim fltSaved As Filter          ' Var to save Filter on first column
    Dim sFilterTLC As String        ' Address of Filter Top Left Corner

    If wksParent.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Set fltSaved = wksParent.AutoFilter.Filters(1) ' Save Filter on 1st col
    End If

    ' Expand filter if needed
    If wksParent.AutoFilter.Range.Address <> wksParent.UsedRange.Address Then
        ExpandFilterRange wksParent, wksParent.AutoFilter.Range(1)
        Set wksParent.AutoFilter.Filters(1) = fltSaved
    End If

    ' Now apply filter to Child
    If wksChild.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        sFilterTLC = "A1"
    Else
        sFilterTLC = wksChild.AutoFilter.Range(1).Address
    End If
    ExpandFilterRange wksChild, wksChild.Range(sFilterTLC)
    If Not (fltSaved Is Nothing) Then                   ' If any filter applied
        If fltSaved.On Then
        ReDim filterArray(fltSaved.Count)
            If fltSaved.Count > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To fltSaved.Count
                    filterArray(i) = fltSaved.Criteria1(i)
                Next i
            Else
                filterArray(1) = fltSaved.Criteria1
            End If
            If fltSaved.Operator Then
                wksChild.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter 1, filterArray(), _
                    fltSaved.Operator, fltSaved.Criteria2
            Else
                wksChild.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter 1, filterArray()
            End If
        Else
            wksChild.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub ExpandFilterRange(ByRef wks As Worksheet, ByRef rngTLC As Range)
Dim rngFilterPoss As Range       ' Possible filtered cells
' Range from Top Left Corner of Filter to Bottom Right of worksheet
Set rngFilterPoss = Range(rngTLC, wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, wks.Columns.Count))
wks.AutoFilterMode = False       ' Turn off Filter
Intersect(rngFilterPoss, wks.UsedRange).AutoFilter      ' Re-apply filter
End Sub
```

Comment: Since my filter works except for the choosing of only displayed fields, it is a better/less code to have a function that looks for EntireRow.Hidden = False

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach if it strikes your interest.  Place this code in the 2nd worksheet (the one you want to update automatically.)  It will run every time you switch to that worksheet.

- Change the 1 in *Set FirstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1")* to the 1st sheet's name.
- Update the 2nd sheet in the same way on the *Set SecondSheet* line.

[Here's a good page on AutoFilter VBA](http://contextures.com/xlautofilter03.html).  Let me know if you've any questions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Header As Range

    Set FirstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1")
    Set Header = FirstSheet.Range("A1")
    Set SecondSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2")

    'Detect whether Autofilter is active, turn on if not
    If SecondSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        'Detect whether a filter is active, clear if so
        If SecondSheet.FilterMode Then SecondSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
        SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End If

    'Grab filter criteria of FirstSheet
    With Header.Parent.AutoFilter
        With .Filters(Header.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then Exit Sub
            'Update SecondSheet to match FirstSheet
            If .Operator = xlAnd Then
                SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, .Criteria1, xlAnd, .Criteria2
            ElseIf .Operator = xlOr Then
                SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, .Criteria1, xlOr, .Criteria2
            ElseIf .Operator = xlFilterValues Then
                SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, .Criteria1, xlFilterValues
            Else
                SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, .Criteria1
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, but it tripped up on SecondSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter

Comment: Bizarre, it works perfectly on my prototype.  It hits that line when autofilter is off for that sheet.  What error# did you receive?

Comment: "Autofilter method or Range class failed". Any way I can use a formula and not VBA for this? Surprised that Excel has such as shortcoming

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to do this using Excel Forumlas, and that's fine, but you might want to consider a third sheet "Reports", where you just build the sheet with some loops.  Just insert a button and assign it to this code, and you will get the results you want, without messing around with your Comments Sheet at all.  It's more of a query Report this way.

Since there aren't any good ways to capture the event of the filter being applied to the Worksheet, other than Worksheet_change, and you would have a lot of unnecessary refreshing happening to your Comments sheet if you tried to tap into that event.. Also, if you did, you'd be knee deep in VB anyway.  So I'd recommend, just inserting that "Reports" sheet and calling it a day.  You just need your header row to match the comments sheet.

```
Sub VisibleReport()

Dim lastProjectRow As Integer
Dim lastCommentRow As Integer
Dim pRow As Integer
Dim cRow As Integer
Dim rRow As Integer

'Clear the previous reports run on "Reports"
Sheets("Reports").Range("A2:B65000").Clear

'Get the last row of the Projects and Comments Sheets
lastProjectRow = Sheets("Projects").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastCommentRow = Sheets("Comments").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Set the ReportRow to start on 2
rRow = 2

'Begin Looping through the rows on the Projects Sheet

For pRow = 2 To lastProjectRow

    If Sheets("Projects").Rows(pRow).Hidden = False Then

        'Set the TempID to the current row's projectID
        tempID = Sheets("Projects").Cells(pRow, 1)

        For cRow = 2 To lastCommentRow
            'Check to see if the Project ID matches on the Comment Sheet, and if so, copy A & B of that Row to Report.
            If (Sheets("Comments").Cells(cRow, 1) = tempID) Then
                Sheets("Reports").Cells(rRow, 1) = Sheets("Comments").Cells(cRow, 1)
                Sheets("Reports").Cells(rRow, 2) = Sheets("Comments").Cells(cRow, 2)

                'increment the Row on the Report Sheet.
                rRow = rRow + 1
            End If
        Next cRow
    End If

Next pRow

'Set the Focus on the Report Sheet.
Sheets("Reports").Activate
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Merry Christmas!  I see the macros and my eyes bug out.  If you're scared of macros or aren't allowed to have them, and array formulas bog down your processor, try this simple normal-formula method (it requires one additional column in your "Project Names" dataset).

Add a new column anywhere in your "Project Names" dataset (I'm using column A here), add a row number to each row of your "Project Name" dataset by doing this =ROW() and dragging it down to the bottom of your dataset.  (Don't hard code it unless you're never going to re-sort your dataset).  You now have a super valuable golden column.

Then try out The following formula (which you can complicate and make fancy later) on a blank worksheet:

=SUBTOTAL(5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS([the first cell in your "Project Name" dataset range (or the value from the cell above this one if this is a subsequent instance of this formula)]+1,1,1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW([last cell in your dataset]),1,1),1))

**If your dataset starts at row one, then just use the cell value above this formula (value should be a blank cell or a header) - otherwise you might need to specify the first row of your dataset in the first formula, and then when you drag down or over your formula, use the row-number result provided in the previous formula.*

Drag the formula down to however many rows you want.  When the first formula is set up right, it will return the first row number of the filtered dataset.  If you drag it down, the next formula down will start at that row number + 1 and provide the next visible row number, etc, etc. until all of the filtered row numbers are accounted for.

Now you have a fancy new list of only the non-filtered row numbers from your dataset.  In the next column over from these row numbers, you can simply do an =INDIRECT(ADDRESS([value from the cell to the left],[some column number (for example, the one holding the project ID)],1,1,[sheet name]),1) in order to get other row details like the ID or Report Name.

You can also use this list of row numbers and Project IDs you created in a COUNTIFS formula or some other mechanism to filter your "notes" dataset.  For example in your "Notes" dataset, you could add =IF(COUNTIFS([the range containing your fancy new list],[this row's value])>0,"Show","Hide").  Then just auto-filter on "Show".

I would post pictures demoing this, but I'm not allowed.  You'll just have to try it out on your own.